# How to correctly enquote string for substitution in command?

Tags: string, bash, ffmpeg, command, substitution

I am trying to pass a generated filter chain to ffmpeg with bash like so:

```
FILTER="-filter_complex \"...\""
ffmpeg -i ... $FILTER ...
```

However, ffmpeg does not like this, telling me

> No such filter: '"'

So, how do I correctly set up the variable for proper substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `-filter_complex` and the `...` part to be passed as two separate arguments, but you need the `...` part to remain intact (as a single argument — not split by whitespace, not undergo filename-expansion, etc.).

The best way to accomplish that is to use an array, and then to expand it by using the `${arrayname[@]}` notation inside double-quotes:

```
FILTER=(-filter_complex '...')
ffmpeg -i ... "${FILTER[@]}" ...
```